# Using flexbox to change layout at different breakpoints

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to arrange a series of elements in a different layout for "mobile" screens vs large screens.

Basically, on mobile screens I want a title to span the entire width at the top, centered. Underneath is an image and a group of icons to the right in the same row.

On larger screens I want the title to be adjacent to the image in the same column, but above the icons (see image for desired results).
[image]

By playing with the flexbox rules and the order property, I can achieve 2/3 of this effect. The way I have it written, I can get the title next to the image, but the icon group is always underneath the image.

[See my fiddle for my attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/ktomasso/vnbt3h4z/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <h1 class="title">This is my title</h1>
    <div class="image">
     <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=300&h=400">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-section">
      <div class="icon">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    order: 2;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.icon-section {
  padding-left: 20px;
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    display: flex;
    order: 3;
  }
}
.icon {
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

I'm not married to using flexbox and I'm flexible with my markup. What I want to avoid, however, is having two instances of my heading and hiding one depending on the screen size. Also because the title will be dynamic, I cannot use absolute positioning.

Comment: This layout may not be possible with the `order` property. Even if it is, it would be quite messy and complex. The simplest method - using flexbox -  would, in my opinion, use `display: none` depending on screen size. I know you want to avoid this. But I think it's the simplest and most reliable method: https://jsfiddle.net/kedr5aya/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just to set the query to work on screen size, like

`@media only screen and (max-width: 500px)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using a combination of flexbox and traditional floats. Basically, I wrote the markup based on the large screen size look, and used flexbox on the mobile size to change the sort order when the elements stack.

[The working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktomasso/t05uxu68/5/) (you'll have to adjust your browser size to see the changes)

HTML:

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="image">
         <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=300&h=400">
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">This is my title</h1>
        <div class="meta">
          <div class="icon-section">
            <div class="icon">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40">
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
      .container {
      max-width: 500px;
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        max-width: 750px;
      }
    }
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: flex-start;
      align-content: flex-start;
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        float: left;
        display: block;
      }
    }
    .image {
      order: 2;
      @media (min-width: 800px){
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
    }
    .meta {
      order: 2;
    } 
    .title {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
       order: 1;
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
        width: auto
      }
    }
    .icon-section {
      float: left;
      order: 3;
      margin-left: 20px;
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
    .icon {
      @media (min-width: 800px) {
       margin-right: 5px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This may work for you, but it looks like you're applying floats to flex items. Any such floats are ignored: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers